# change image color in black and white and sepia on button click using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have two different buttons. one for black and white and other for sepia . i need to change color of image on click of buttons.  Is there any jquery script to change image color in black and white and sepia color.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply guys. I found a great solution for this with css.On click of black and white button we can call this css.

```
.blackwhite-image
{
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter  id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333  0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /*  Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

and for sepia

```
    .sepia-image
    {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter     id=\'old-timey\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.14 0.45 0.05 0 0 0.12 0.39 0.04 0 0 0.08 0.28 0.03 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#old-timey"); 
-webkit-filter: sepia(1);
    -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
    -moz-filter: sepia(100%);
    -ms-filter: sepia(100%);
    -o-filter: sepia(100%);
    filter: sepia(100%);
    }
```

This is working great for me..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have uploaded both versions of the image file -- the black & white version and the sepia version. Attach a click event to both buttons that adds the corresponding image to the page. Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="output"></div>
<button id="bw">Black and white</button>
<button id="sep">Sepia</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#bw').click(function() {
  $('#output').html('<img src="blackandwhite.png" />');
});

$('#sep').click(function() {
  $('#output').html('<img src="sepia.png" />');
});
```

Comment: but i don't have not image version black and white and sepia. Because users are uploading there images and after uploading image they can see there image and can change color and size etc. of image.Is there not any other trick?

Comment: @user1523311 - Image tinting via CSS styling might be the way to go. Check out this resource http://www.impressivewebs.com/image-tint-blend-css/ . The basic idea is to wrap your image within an element and tint the background color of the element.